# Is 薬指 related to the Latin term "digitus medicinalis"?

Tags: etymology

薬指 ("medicine finger", ring finger) is interestingly similar to the Latin term for ring finger, "digitus medicinalis". Are they etymologically related?

Comment: Can you read this? http://gogen-allguide.com/ku/kusuriyubi.html

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not. The likely reason has to do with Buddhist statuary: a particular buddha called Yakushi has his fourth finger bent in many poses.

More about the finger on the Japanese Wikipedia:

[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/薬指](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%96%AC%E6%8C%87)

More about this particular Buddha on the English Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhaisajyaguru